# My Raspi4 hdmi won’t sound

Tags: raspbian, audio, pi-4, hdmi

### What's happening?

My raspberry pi4 won’t sound HDMI.

(AV jack is working fine)

#### Raspi information

**environment**

OS - Raspberry Pi OS with desktop 2020-12(Flash with December 2nd 2020 image and run `apt full-upgrade`)

SD - 32GB

Monitor - BENQ

HDMI port - hdmi0

Monitors HDMI port - HDMI1

Raspi Volume - 100%

Monitor Volume - 10%

**I did this**

I had comment out

```
hdmi_drive=2
```

But monitor still no sound.

Comment: HDMI sound should work out of the box. Are you sure you're using the right port (the one close to the USB-C connector)?

Comment: There is **NO** "Official Raspbian"

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I mean ['Raspberry Pi OS'](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/).

Comment: Yes. I am using HDMI0 port which close to the USB-C connector.

Comment: Have you tried running sudo raspi-config -> System options -> Audio and selecting the correct HDMI port for Audio output?

Comment: Yes. And it only have option **0** HDMI 1  **1** Headphones... It doesnt work either...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same HDMI lack-of-sound problem, except that I was trying to connect the Pi to a Vizio TV. Used the HDMI0 port closest to the USB-C connector and uncommented hdmi_drive=2 in /boot/config.txt to no effect. Ran `sudo raspi-config`, checked `Audio` in `System Options`, and found the same "HDMI" and "Headphones" options as noted in the comments above, with "HDMI" apparently selected.

At that point, I tried something seemingly unintuitive based on past experience with badly written software. I selected "Headphones" and "OK" to change the stored setting from whatever it was to "Headphones". I then went back into `Audio`, selected "HDMI", and "OK to change the stored setting to "HDMI".

And with that, HDMI sound worked.

Answer (score 0):

Or, in the case of Raspberry Pi 3+ running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), the options may be slightly different in Audio > System Options.

0 Headphones

1 MAI PCM i2-hifi-0

Select Option 1 and the end result should be the same - sound over HDMI.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/136119)